# How to search text with '\t \n \r' characters in UI

Tags: java, html, angularjs

User content from backend: `select \ta, \tb, \tc from table;`

When rendering in HTML, content shown to user : `select a, b, c from table;`

When user searches for `select a` in search field, this data is not shown as it does not match the underlying data.

Similarly, the content has extra spaces which are all removed when showing in UI automatically by HTML, but search fails because of that.

What is a solution that can enable user to search?

Comment: define "search". If it's a filter, then you can always make a custom one, that strips any special characters and then searches for a match in that string

Comment: yes filtering a table with the given text.